# Should we split "call together" & "gather together"?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, phrasal-verbs

When an organization sends invitations to companies for a planned conference, the verbs "gather together" and "call together" seem to be interchangable in this context. Should the object stay between the verb and the preposition?

> The organization X called _____ together for the conference.
>
> The organization X gathered ____ together at the conference.

Can they be used interchangeably?

Comment: there are in different time phases - one needs to call together before the clan can/will gather together.

Answer (score 1):

Literally, *organization X* [***called***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/call) *Y together*:

> [WITH OBJECT]
>
> Announce or decide that (an event, especially a meeting, election, or
>   strike) is to happen:

But *organization X* [***gathered***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/gather) *Y together*:

> [WITH OBJECT]
>
> Bring together and take in from scattered places or sources:

*Calling Y together* is a part of the process of *gathering Y together*, but it is acceptable to substitute *call Y together* as a [*metonym*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/metonym) of *gather together*. It is also acceptable to substitute *gather Y together* as a [*metonym*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/metonym) of *call together*. Specifically, referring to the whole in terms of a part, or the part in terms of the whole, is a *[synecdoche](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/synecdoche)*.